# Best way to get the ID of the last inserted row on SQLite

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

On iPhone, what's the best way to get the ID of the last inserted row on an SQLite Database using FMDB ?

Is there a better way rather than doing :

```
SELECT MAX(ID)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you can guarantee that your `ID` column is an auto-increment column, `MAX(ID)` is fine.

But to cover any case, there's a specialized SQLite function called [`LAST_INSERT_ROWID()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html):

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ROWID();
```

In FMDB, you use the `-lastInsertRowId` method (which internally runs the above):

```
int lastId = [fmdb lastInsertRowId];
```

Comment: Why [fmdb lastInsertRowId] always returns 0 for me?

Comment: @landonandrey `lastInsertRowId` works on a specific connection. The connection that you're using has just been opened, so there is no inserted row ID. You can reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976670/fmdb-lastinsertrowid-always-0) for more information.

Comment: I found that `LAST_INSERT_ROWID()` is connection specific. So if you're opening/closing your connection it won't work the way you might expect.

Answer (score 9):

The function [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) is what you're looking for.  Having just checked out the source code for FMDB, there seems to be a method on [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.h) called `-lastInsertRowId` that wraps the function.

Comment: @FMDatabase link does not exists

Answer (score 5):

**For swift 5 use this code**

```
let lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db)
```

for example

```
if sqlite3_exec(db, stringSql, nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error Insert: \(errmsg)")
}

let lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
print(lastRowId) // its gives you last insert id

if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error finalizing prepared statement: \(errmsg)")
}
statement = nil

//*** close data base
if sqlite3_close(db) != SQLITE_OK {
    print("error closing database")
}
db = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var rowid: Int = Int(contactDB.lastInsertRowId())
```