# FMDB lastinsertRowID always 0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, fmdb

Hya.

I have implemented FMDB in my app. I am trying to get the last row id from one of my databases with this

```
FMDatabase *bdb=[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
    NSString *str;
    if([bdb open]){
        int lastId=[bdb lastInsertRowId];
        FMResultSet *s = [bdb executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT budget FROM data WHERE ROWID='%d'",lastId]];
        if([s next])
        {
            str= [s stringForColumnIndex:0];
        }
    }
```

the problem i have is that lastId is always 0 , although there are 3 entries currently in the database. 
Any1 have any idea why is this happening?

EDIT: the database is created like this:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &basicDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, BUDGET INTEGER)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(basicDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
               DLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
           sqlite3_close(basicDB);

        } else {
           DLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lastInsertRowId` works on a specific connection.
The connection that you're using has just been opened, so there is no inserted row ID.

(The purpose of `lastInsertRowId` is to allow your app to know the ID of a record that has just been `INSERT`ed.)

To read data from the last record, use something like this:

```
SELECT budget FROM data WHERE rowid = (SELECT max(rowid) FROM data)
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for your explanation. But supposing i would not use FMDB but SQLITE API , would select_last_row_id() behave in a similar fashion?

Comment: Yes; that's how `lastInsertRowId` is implemented.

Comment: so how does an INSERT query know to insert a row at a corresponding rowid? i mean sure, the rowid is set to autoincrement, but in a supposed exampple like this:   the database contains 3 items, whith rowids 1,2 and 3. you insert a fourth item; sql puts it at rowid 4; then you delete the new row; after that you do another INSERT; the new row will have rowid 5, even though at the time of the last INSERT ,the max_rowid was 3.

Comment: Thank you very much. The document you linked was revealing as to how things work.  Now this sqlite_sequence - how can it be accessed in fmdb? smth like `SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='table_name' ` ?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet; irght now i used the max(rowid) But i'll try it and post the result here for future reference.    Thanks again for all your info - really really good!

Comment: @landonandrey To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.