# Autoincrement value in transactions body

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, transactions

How can i get the autoincrement value in thansaction body?

Code

```
public void insertAllStudents(List<Student> students) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME +" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
    db.beginTransaction();
    for (Student student: students) {
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindString(2, student.getId());
        statement.bindString(3, student.getFirstName());
        statement.bindString(4, student.getLastName());
        statement.bindLong(5, student.getBirthday());
        statement.execute();
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

The first column (_ID) is autoincrement field. Is it opportunity to get this value?
student.getId() -that's not id from database, that's different id.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to use db.insert(), this method returns the id of the inserted row - see [Get generated id after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409751/get-generated-id-after-insert).

There is also a specialised SQLite function to get the last inserted row if you'd prefer to keep compiling statements, see [Best way to get the ID of the last inserted row on SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867404/best-way-to-get-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row-on-sqlite)

edit: example using db.insert().  This isn't tested but should be pretty close to functional.

```
db.beginTransaction();
boolean success = true;
final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (final Student student: students) {
    values.put("student_id", student.getId());
    values.put("first_name", student.getFirstName());
    values.put("last_name", student.getLastName());
    values.put("birthday", student.getBirthday());
    final long id = db.insert("my_table", null, values);
    if (id == -1) {
        success = false;
        break;
    }

    // TODO do your thing with id here.
}
if (success) {
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: db.insert() takes a lot of time so i using transactions for inserting data. But can i get id value before i finish transaction?

Comment: Yes, the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ROWID()` should work, even within a transaction - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376773/in-sqlite3-can-a-select-succeed-within-a-transaction-of-insert

Comment: @Andrew by the way, you should be able to use db.insert() inside a transaction - it just compiles a statement under the hood.

Comment: How can i use db.insert() ? Can you show an example please.

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `statement.execute()`, you can do [`statement.executeInsert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#executeInsert()). This returns the row ID of the inserted row. Or, as @Tom suggested, you can use `db.insert()` instead, and it will also return the inserted row ID. Using a compiled statement like you are doing now is faster though.

If you want to try the `db.insert()` approach, it would look something like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (Student student: students) {
    // use whatever constants you have for column names instead of these:
    values.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_ID, student.getId());
    values.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_FIRSTNAME, student.getFirstName());
    values.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_LASTNAME, student.getLastName());
    values.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_BIRTHDAY, student.getBirthday());
    db.insert(StudentEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```